# Value controller is not updated with factory

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, controller, ionic-framework, factory

I am developing an application with Ionic and I have a problem updating a value of the controller and factory

The value is not automatically updated when I change from another controller

Sorry for my English but I speak Spanish

Factory.js

```
aplicacion.factory("parametrosUsuarioFactory", function(){
var datos={
  nombre : '',
  imagenDePerfil:''
}

var interfaz = {
  actualizarNombre: function(nombreRecibido){
      datos.nombre = nombreRecibido;
  },
 obtenerNombre: function(){
        //console.log("Datos adentro:"+datos);
        return datos.nombre;
    },
    actualizarImagenDePerfil: function(imagenDePerfilRecibido){
        datos.imagenDePerfil = imagenDePerfilRecibido;
    },
    obtenerImagenDePerfil: function(){
        //console.log("Datos adentro:"+datos);
        return datos.imagenDePerfil;
    }


}
return interfaz;
})
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.nombre = parametrosUsuarioFactory.obtenerNombre();
$scope.imagenDePerfil = parametrosUsuarioFactory.obtenerImagenDePerfil();
```

index.html

```
<p id="nombreMenu" style="padding: 10px 10px 4px;">{{nombre}}</p>
<div id="contenedorImagenDePerfil">
<img id="imagenDePerfil" src="{{imagenDePerfil}}"/>
</div>
```

Controller2.js

```
 parametrosUsuarioFactory.actualizarNombre(data.data.full_name);
parametrosUsuarioFactory.actualizarImagenDePerfil(data.data.profile_picture);
parametrosUsuarioFactory.actualizarIdUsuario(data.data.id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are assigning your scope variables to the results of functions in your server and Angular can't watch those for updates.

You have a couple options. There is a way to watch a function as [described here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2658-using-scope-watch-to-watch-functions-in-angularjs.htm), but I find that somewhat confusing.

You can broadcast from your service that a change was made and then watch for that in your controller and update the scope variables appropriately. Here's a sample...

**javascript**

```
var aplicacion = angular.module('app', []);

aplicacion.factory("parametrosUsuarioFactory", function($rootScope) {
    var datos = {
        nombre: '',
        imagenDePerfil: ''
    }

    var interfaz = {
        actualizarNombre: function(nombreRecibido) {
            datos.nombre = nombreRecibido;
            $rootScope.$broadcast("datosActualizado");
        },
        obtenerNombre: function() {
            return datos.nombre;
        },
        actualizarImagenDePerfil: function(imagenDePerfilRecibido) {
            datos.imagenDePerfil = imagenDePerfilRecibido;
            $rootScope.$broadcast("datosActualizado");
        },
        obtenerImagenDePerfil: function() {
            return datos.imagenDePerfil;
        }
    }
    return interfaz;
});

aplicacion.controller("controller1", function($scope, parametrosUsuarioFactory) {
    $scope.obtenerDatos = function() {
        $scope.nombre = parametrosUsuarioFactory.obtenerNombre();
        $scope.imagenDePerfil = parametrosUsuarioFactory.obtenerImagenDePerfil();
    };

    $scope.$on("datosActualizado", function(){ $scope.obtenerDatos() });

    $scope.obtenerDatos();
});

aplicacion.controller("controller2", function($scope, parametrosUsuarioFactory) {
    $scope.actualizarValores = function() {
        parametrosUsuarioFactory.actualizarNombre("nombre de controller2");
        parametrosUsuarioFactory.actualizarImagenDePerfil("imagen de controller2");
    }
});
```

**html**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="controller1">
        <h2>controller1</h2>
        Nombre: {{nombre}}<br>
        Imagen: {{imagenDePerfil}}
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div ng-controller="controller2">
        <h2>controller2</h2>
        <button ng-click="actualizarValores()">
            Actualizar valores de controller1
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a super-simplified example of one approach. Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2zqfmff/).

P.S. Don't apologize for your English - it's much better than my Spanish. :)

Comment: You're absolutely right, I'm never listening to some change, I tried the device and run properly thank you very much.